# "[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart": while trying to start the server

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mern, web-development-server, nodemon

I keep running into this error while trying to run my code...

```
[nodemon] 2.0.15
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
```

This is the code that I'm trying to run:

```
import app from "./server";
import mongodb from "mongodb";
import dotenv from "dotenv";

//configuiring dotenv for use
dotenv.config();
const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

const port = process.env.PORT || 8000; // if the port(5000 in this one) from dotenv file cant be accesed then access 8000

MongoClient.connect(process.env.RESTREVIEWS_DB_URI, {
  poolsize: 50, //max no of users at a time
  wtimeout: 2500, //timeout after 2500 ms
  useNewUrlParse: true,  
})
  .catch((err) => {
    //if connection fails
    console.error(err.stack);
    process.exit(1);
  })
  .then(async (client) => {
    app.listen(port, () => {
      console.log(`listening on the port ${port}`);
    });
  });

// --   AND WE ARE DONE WITH THE DATABASE AND HAVE STARTED OUR WEB SERVER  --
```

I've tried changing the Execution policy to Unrestricted mode and Remote but it still doesn't work. It would be great if someone could help me figure out what I'm doing wrong!

Comment: What happens when you run `node server.js`? Nodemon can break sometimes so that might be the issue.

Comment: Nothing... It just prompts for the next input on running `node server.js`

Answer (score 0):

Try reverting nodemon version to 1.2.1 will fix the problem.

Comment: Doesn't work... It shows this error message:

`exception in nodemon killing node
ReferenceError: primordials is not defined`